# Compress / Zip a folder periodically but use minimal CPU?

Tags: windows-7, compression, zip, 7-zip

Similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/81777/compressing-a-folder-periodically) except, I need it to run with minimal CPU on the background? Also, if there's a 7zip solution that will be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are zipping up in the GUI with 7zip you can simply hit the background button which reduces the CPU priority (8 to 4 or IDLE) of the process.  You can hit the button again to toggle to the foreground.  There are some screen grabs to illustrate [here](http://ram.kossboss.com/7zip-foreground-vs-background-pc/).

If you are looking to do this from the command line or scripted, you can do this by using `start /low /wait command` to similarly start a command (and wait for it to return before moving on) which again only runs when the system is IDLE.

Finally, if you are using `powershell`, check out [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/268273/108132) over on ServerFault.